# Losing props in react native when navigating backwards

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a simple problem: I have a parent component that navigates to a child component, the child component is supposed to update the state on the parent component when the child navigates backwards (`this.props.navigation.navigate("parentComponent", { params })` ). According to the docs this should be easy: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

The navigation action is treated like a `goBack` action if the screen already exists. However when I do this and try to `console.log` the props in the parents screen after going back it shows it as empty.

Parent.js

```
 <View style={styles.availabilitycontainer} visible={true}>
          <View style={styles.titlegroupcontainer}>
            <Text style={styles.abouttitle}>Schedule Availability</Text>
            {/*Redirect to edit schedule*/} 
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.cameracantainer}
              onPress={() =>
                this.props.navigation.navigate("ChildComponent")
              }
            >
              <Image source={Editoutline} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <ProfileAvalability />
        </View>
```

Child.js

```
async submitToBackend(){
    /* Code to submit to backend omitted */
  this.props.navigation.navigate('ParentComponent', { params });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigate doesn't really work that way. If it detects the ParentComponent is already there in the stack, it will simply bring it forward and not necessarily rerender/reload.

What I suggest is pass a second param as a function that will perform the changes, eg:

```
submitData(data) {
  setState(data)
}
```

then when you call the child:

```
props.navigation.navigate("ChildComponent", { submitData })
```

then inside the ChildComponent, when you're done processing, call submitData([insert your data here]), then that function will perform the write on the ParentComponent. This assumes you're using useState().

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes using a callback function was my initial solution but React gives me the following warning: `"We found non-serializable values in the navigation state, which can break usage such as persisting and restoring state. This might happen if you passed non-serializable values such as function, class instances etc. in params. If you need to use functions in your options, you can use 'navigation.setOptions' instead."`

Comment: I can suppress the warning I don't think it would be an issue so I was looking for a better solution

Comment: How are you passing the function? That said, passing functions around is like recommended (I really should downvote my own answer.. ha!). Two other options - if you have multiple screens and lots of state to manage, I highly suggest using Redux. Alternatively, use AsyncStorage to just store something quick and retrieve it. Hope this helps.